# Associate Button Value with Query Results In Seperate Tables

Tags: php, sql

I have this query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_tasks_report WHERE TASK_ID=$taskid ORDER BY WEEK_ID");
$current_week_id = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
if($current_week_id != $row['WEEK_ID'])
{
  if($current_week_id != - 1)
   {      
      echo "</table>";
   }
echo "<table>";

echo "<tr class='no-border'><td class='no-border'><div class='task-detail-title'>Week Number: " . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "</div></td></tr>";         
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th width='100'>Day</th>";
echo "<th width='75'>Start</th>";
echo "<th width='75'>End</th>";
echo "<th width='100'>Billable Hours</th>";
echo "<th width='100'>Non Billable Hours</th>";
echo "</tr>";
$current_week_id = $row['WEEK_ID'];
}
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['DAY'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['START'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['END'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='tdclass'>" . $row['NON_BILLABLE_HOURS'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
  if($current_week_id != - 1)
   {      
      echo "</table>";
   }
```

This provides me with seperate tables for each week ID.  However I am looking to get buttons to display below each table which are associated with the results above.  Is it possible to add a button with the value of WEEK_ID.  Currently if I add a button to the top  and the bottom  with value:

```
<input type='image' name='submit' src="image/button.jpg" value=" . $row['WEEK_ID'] . ">
```

It doesn't show the right ID for the top tables and it shows nothing for the bottom.  I do understand why this is but is there anyway I can associate this button underneath the table?

Comment: Show als the whole nonworking code that we can see where exactly you set the buttons.

Comment: I placed the buttons after both </table>  the button code is above.  I just need the value to take itself from the WEEK_ID of the week above but it's not associating itself with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this outside the PHP tag:

```
<input type="image" name="submit" src="image/button.jpg" value="<?php echo $row['WEEK_ID'] ?>">
```

Use this inside the PHP tag.

```
echo '<input type="image" name="submit" src="image/button.jpg" value="' . $row['WEEK_ID'] . '">';
```

Comment: Sorry it's already within the PHP tag.  The issue is that it is not recognising the WEEK_ID associated with table above.

Comment: Well, if your want to associate it give the table an `id="$row['WEEK_ID']"`. Then again if you told us what you are trying to accomplish the answer might be more direct. What should happen when you click the button?